# File server to SharePoint Online: folder to document library structure diff tool?

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-online

Do you know if there is any kind of tool (it would be cool if it is for free) that compares the file structure of a folder in a File Server to a SharePoint Online Document Library and tells you the difference?

The point is we are getting hands on a partially migrated File Server to SharePoint Online and the migration status of some folders is unknown to us. We already have a 3rd party migration tool to finish the migration but we need to know what is still pending to be uploaded. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use sharegate for our migration. In your situation I might just run migrations on small sections with it set to "skip existing". That doesn't directly answer your question though.

In your case I would map both the File server and the SharePoint online instance as drives on a computer (using WebDAV) and hack together an app in your favorite language to compare the two directory structures.

Here is a java program that does that:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Launcher {
static PrintWriter fileOut;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File fileStore = new File("N:\\"); //filestore dir top level
    File sp = new File("M:\\");//sp directory top level (mapped)

    File out = new File("C:\\Temp\\results.txt");
    fileOut = new PrintWriter(out);

    recurse(fileStore, sp);
    fileOut.close();
}
private static void recurse(File dir1, File dir2)
{
    File [] dirFiles;
    if(dir2 == null)
    dirFiles = new File[0];
    else
    dirFiles=dir2.listFiles();
    File match;
    for(File f1 : dir1.listFiles())
    {
    System.out.println(f1.getAbsolutePath());
    match=null;
    for(File f2:dirFiles)
        if(f1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(f2.getName()))
        match=f2;
    if(f1.isDirectory() && f1.canRead())
        try{
        recurse(f1,match);
        }
    catch(Exception e){}
    else if (match == null)
        fileOut.write(f1.getAbsolutePath()+"\r\n");
    }
}
}
```

It writes to the given text file each file that is not in the 2nd directory structure.
You could run this code in an IDE like eclipse.

Comment: Hei Aaron, thanks for the response. We are also using Sharegate for migration so the first option is what we are already doing right now, but still not exactly what I'm looking for. Coding is also an option I thought about, but first I want to know if already exists this kind of tool.

Comment: OK cool, what kind of output are you looking for in this directory compare? I might have some a program already written, as I've had to compare some items on our SharePoint install.

Comment: Just the list of files (with full path on file server if possible) that are not present in the document library in SharePoint Online.

Comment: I added a sample program I had

Comment: Hei Aaron, I wanted to avoid mapping the document library, as in our case it weights more than 60GB but I'll give it a try anyway. Thank you!

Comment: We have several ~200GB document libraries mapped and it works well.

Comment: Well, we ended creating our own tool in c#. We did it by connecting with Client Object Model to SharePoint Online and getting the items of the document library in batches getting the full path (FileRef for those who want to try it) for each item. Then using the cmd dir command (dir /s /b) we got a txt file as input for the file server structure. Compared both sets of paths and extracted the difference on both sides. Thanks for the  help Aaron.